# CLLocationManager not updating location

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, core-location

Problem is location manager is not updating location. 
The `(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLoc fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLoc`    functions gets called but it displays the new location as the same old location.

Following is my piece of code:
In my viewDidLoad method i am creating the object of CLLocationManager

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    // created a timer to call locationUpdate method 
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 target: self selector:  @selector(locationUpdate) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];    

}

-(void)locationUpdate
{

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLoc
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLoc
{

    NSLog(@"in locationmanager did update %f",newLoc.coordinate.latitude);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = 
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLoc.coordinate, 0.01,      0.02);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    {
        MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.02);
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, span);
        [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
        [_mapView regionThatFits:region];

    }
```

The value which i am getting in NSLog(@"in locationmanager did update %f",newLoc.coordinate.latitude) is always the same even-though i had moved for more than 2 kilometers starting from current location.

Please help me to how to get exact new location whenever there is a locationupdate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you restarting that poor location manager using an NSTimer? **If you had read the docs, you would have found out that it's enough to call** `startUpdatingLocation` **once!**

Comment: Before adding a timer, i had tried to call [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] once in view did load, but in the locationUpdate delegate method i was getting the new location as the same old one.

Comment: that may be because... euh... you don't move?

Comment: NO.. even after moving for more than 3 kilometers i am not getting the new location in didUpdateLocation method. But when i quit the application and start it for the first time only new location is getting updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Question. Solution for my problem was `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 target: self selector:  @selector(locationUpdate) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];    
`  Problem I had :- Unable to update the location and hence compass needle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are stopping the location manager with

```
[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

in

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLoc
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLoc
```

. This delegate method gets called EVERY time the user moves and can give you old (cached) data at the beginning, so by stopping it right away when you get your first location fix you probably get a cached location each time. The fix is simple, just don't stop the location manager there but rather when your viewController disappears or at a similar useful place.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually i was testing the app on iPad with wifi.. and since it doesn't have a gps chip in it i was not getting any location  updates... the code works on iphone...